# Use internal class as T in List<T>

Tags: c#

Code:

> Assembly with internal class (Example class)

```
internal class Abc
{
    int a;
    float pos;
}
```

How do i make a `List<T>` with T as internal class `Abc`?

It's an external assembly which means that I can't do `InternalsVisibleTo`, and the assembly isn't made by me so I can't just edit it.

Comment: How do you want/expect the client code to use it?

Comment: `List<Abc> a = new List<Abc>()` or `Classes<Abc>.Find()`

Comment: If it's going to be used externally why make it internal? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you have a variable that holds an instance of that type `Abs`?

Comment: No, i don't have it.

Comment: Wait, if the class is `internal` and it's in an external assembly you didn't create, how do you know the class exists?

Comment: If you don't have a value, how are you going to use a list? What will you store in that list?

Comment: I've used tools to browse the code, thats how i know that the class exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a variable of the type `Abc` you can do the following:

```
// Get the value of type Abc with its runtime type.
var abc = ...;

// Variable listOfAbcs will be of type List<Abc>.
var listOfAbcs = CreateList(abs);

// Local function to create a list.
List<T> CreateList<T>(T value) => new List<T>();
```

Alternatively you can create a list with reflections and access it via `IList` interface.

Comment: It's possible to create a variable with `Abc` type using reflection and that worked, Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, if you create it with reflection the type of the variable will be `object`. So you could simply use `new List<object>()` instead to store your values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `List<T>` issue is a moot point. Really what you seem to be asking is "how do I expose an internal implementation to a public API?"

There are a few options for this:

- Use an interface (if implementations are related by functionality)
- Use an abstract class (if derived types are related by identity)
- Use a base class (if derived types are related by identity and the base class may also be instantiated)

**Example**

Consider `AbcBase` and `AbcInternal` are in a separate assembly.

```
// Provides a publicly available class.
// Note, the internal default constructor will only allow derived types from the same assembly, meaning the class is essentially sealed to the outside world
public class AbcBase
{
    internal AbcBase()
    {
    }

    protected int a;
    protected float pos;

    public static List<AbcBase> CreateList()
    {
        return new List<AbcBase>()
        {
            new AbcInternal(1, 2.3f),
            new AbcInternal(4, 5.6f)
        };
    }
}

internal sealed class AbcInternal : AbcBase
{
    public AbcInternal(int a, float pos)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.pos = pos;
    }
}
```

Consider `Program` is in the consuming assembly, or in other words, references the assembly where `AbcBase` and `AbcInternal` are implemented

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<AbcBase> list = AbcBase.CreateList();
    }
}
```

Note that the public implementation is exposed through `AbcBase` but not the internal implementation.

```
public class AbcImpl : AbcBase
{
}
```

Note, the above will cause a compiler error because the contructor in `AbcBase` is internal, therefore this class cannot be overridden from a different assembly.

> 'AbcBase.AbcBase()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: That's good answer, but OP has no control over the assembly where the `Abc` class is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `internal` restricts access to the type to only the containing assembly.